# Last chapter number

Tags: numbering, chapters

Is there a way similar to what is achieved by the `lastpage` package to get the Last Chapter number? I would then like to use this information to design chapter headings.

Comment: The package `totcount` should help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An option with the [`totcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/totcount) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{chapter}

\begin{document}

This document has~\total{chapter} chapters.
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

And here's an option without packages:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{totchap}

\providecommand\totchap{} 

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \setcounter{totchap}{\value{chapter}}%
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
    \string\gdef\string\totchap{\number\value{totchap}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

This document has~\totchap\ chapters.
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```